# NSInputStream send NSStreamEventEndEncountered after Facebook connexion

Tags: ios, node.js, socket.io

I use [SocketIO project](https://github.com/pkyeck/socket.IO-objc) on my iOS app to connect to my node.js server and everything works great until I choose to connect to facebook. When I connect to Facebook I send some data to my server and he answer with some data like "user already connected, user created in database" etc. And after that, my NSInputStream seems to be at 0 and so my connexion is closed. I don't know what to do, I spent 14 hours on that and still get this issue...

Can you help me with ?

Edit: Looks like the problem is in [SRWebSocket.m](https://github.com/square/SocketRocket/blob/master/SocketRocket/SRWebSocket.m) line 1462

For more details I added some log :

```
            case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable: {
            SRFastLog(@"NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable %@", aStream);
            const int bufferSize = 2048;
            uint8_t buffer[bufferSize];

            while (_inputStream.hasBytesAvailable) {
                int bytes_read = [_inputStream read:buffer maxLength:bufferSize];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    NSLog(@"BYTES_READ = %i", bytes_read);
                });
                if (bytes_read > 0) {
                    [_readBuffer appendBytes:buffer length:bytes_read];
                } else if (bytes_read < 0) {
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        NSLog(@"ERROR = %@", _inputStream.streamError);
                    });
                    [self _failWithError:_inputStream.streamError];
                }

                if (bytes_read != bufferSize) {
                    break;
                }
            };
            [self _pumpScanner];
            break;
        }
```

And the result :

```
onData 5:::{"name":"initalLogin","args":[{"guid":"af78bdf0-f17d-ede2-7dd6-22708d1330f7","usedWithFaceBook":true}]}
start/reset timeout
CURRRENT SIZE = 0
READ BUFFER LENTGH = 373
event
CURRRENT SIZE = 0
BYTES_READ = 0
NSStreamEventEndEncountered <__NSCFInputStream: 0xab21660>
Reason = Stream end encountered
onDisconnect()
DECONNEXION = The operation couldn’t be completed. (SocketIOError error -4.)
```

Comment: Have you got the solution for this ? I am getting the same error when I use SRWebsocket for my project . Any alternatives ??